# How to add Out of Stack Label to Product in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm looking for the correct solution to label the products which are out of stock but until now didn't find the right solution. I'm using the ULTIMO template from INFORTIS. I've tried the following without success:

```
$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product);

$qty $stock->getQty();

if($qty <= 0)
{
    <span class="out-of-stock"><span>Sold Out</span></span>
}
```

Any idea what else could I try?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); 
$_product = $model->load($product_id); 
$stocklevel = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
                ->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();
if($stocklevel <= 0)
{
    <span class="out-of-stock"><span>Sold Out</span></span>
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, should I put this in the view.phtml and in which position?

Comment: where ever you want brother for ex after price or before product name

Answer (score 0):

```
$product_model =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$product_id = $product_model ->getIdBySku($productsku);
$productload = $product_model ->load($product_id);

$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productload );

if($stock <= 0)
{

<span class="out-of-stock"><span>Sold Out</span></span></pre>

}
```

Comment: thanks for this, where should I put this in the view.phtml file? thanks

Comment: It depends in which phtml file you have declared the view page. Please refer your layout in order to exact phtml file where you can put the above code